# Can you reconstruct tree rings in Datomic?

Tags: datomic

I have a bunch of facts and when they became known.
If I insert them in order it is possible to reconstruct a consistent Datomic DB... but can I insert them in order but have Datomic use the in order times such that I can query using Datomic asof with the historical times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [set the `:db/txInstant`](http://docs.datomic.com/transactions.html#sec-5-5) on a transaction. I think that's a common approach for restoring facts from an old database into a brand new one (a process called decanting).

However, as the docs note, be careful to never manually insert a `:db/txInstant` that's older than any existing transaction or newer than the transactor's clock time. Doing so will make your new database unusable.

Comment: That is correct. Additional description of setting :db/txInstant on import is here: http://docs.datomic.com/best-practices.html#set-txinstant-on-imports